# Stripe SSDs for Host cache in VMWare

Tags: cisco, blade-server, cisco-ucs

I have some blades that management purchased some SSD's to do host caching.

Currently, we have raid 1 SD cards for our hypervisor. I need to add these SSD's in raid 0 so they can quickly host cache. I know what to do in VMWare, however I cant figure out how to set up the UCS service profile to allow for this. The tutorials says to use local disk configuration, and I tried that, however that doesn't seem to be what I am looking for with my setup. I will not be using the SSD's for a hypervisor install, but for host caching

SD: Hypervisor (Raid 1)
SSD: Host cache (Raid 0)

I am running VMware 6.0. 
UCS 3.1(2c)

Comment: AFAIK you need a [Local Disk Configuration Policy](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/unified_computing/ucs/ucs-manager/GUI-User-Guides/Server-Mgmt/3-1/b_Cisco_UCS_Manager_Server_Mgmt_Guide_3_1/server_related_policies.html#d42380e8111a1635), if that is what you are referring to when you say you think it's not what you are looking for, please clarify why.

Comment: We already use a local disk configuration policy for our SD cards. Can you stack them? I was under the impression you could only use one per service profile @hertitu